# 1996 Toyota Camry - ignition or wiring

Tags: toyota, camry

My car won't start I turn the key and nothing happens no click or turning of the engine. When I wait after a while the car makes a beeping noise like it resests itself then it starts but as soon as I turn it off same thing. Now I'm having no luck of starting it. What could it be?

Comment: How do I fix this

Answer (score 3):

Your immobilizer is immobilizing ;) Your car has a security feature called an immobiliser which will prevent the car from starting, or will make it die after being driven only a short distance if the key is not in the ignition or you didn't press a hidden switch in time.

Sometimes these systems malfunction, causing the car to die even though you've done everything you're supposed to.

Comment: What does that mean sorry I'm not really familiar with that

Comment: Your car's anti-theft system is preventing you from starting it.

Comment: Can I fix this myself

Comment: This will likely be a Toyota service activity: reset your key

Comment: You can only fix it with special software and cables.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help very helpful I hope that's what it is

Comment: So it was an aftermarket security system and I removed it and my car starts fine thank you for your help

Comment: This answer would be much more useful to the next person with the exact same question if you capture the flow of comments above as a series of steps in the answer itself.  Currently, when I open the answer, I only see the very first comment.

Comment: His vehicle was a 96. Immobilizer was not introduced til a few years later. While it does have an anti theft system, it does not yet have the immobilizer unit.

Comment: @NickPotterton - If you read through the comments, you can see this was believed to be an aftermarket system which was imposing upon the running condition. Your "answer" was a comment, so I've converted it as such.